Cloning contribution pages
I am trying to clone a contribution page. I tried going to Manage Contribution Pages and selecting Clone. When I click on Clone, it brings me back to all contribution pages without creating a clone.

Hi Brianna, do you have sufficient permissions?

Check for any erros in logs

I tested on dmaster and worked as expected. https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/contribute?reset=1

I believe I have sufficient permissions, as I was able to copy pages in the past.

What version are you using?  Do you have AdminUI enabled?  I think there was a bug like this in a previous version of AdminUI.
